# Why didn't Thor bifrost this character into the Sun?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

Thor's Stormbreaker has got the Bifrost capability. Why didn't he simply use this to transport

> Thanos

into the Sun when he arrived on Earth in *Avengers: Endgame*?

Comment: Doesn’t work, it was # 3,000 in the list of all possible futures seen by Dr. Strange 

Comment: Do you mean "when he arrived on Earth at the end of *Infinity War*"?

Comment: @F1Krazy No. I am talking about *Endgame*..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There would be zero point in doing so as the only winning outcome is exactly what we see in the film as indicated by Doctor Strange. But to play along with the question, why wouldn't he? I'd imagine it's probably best explained in *Thor: Rangarok*, the Bifrost isn't some tamper proof system, people can hijack into it and can fall out of it, as Loki and Thor do when fighting Hela.

If Thanos could simply jump out of it there'd be no point in trying to transport him somewhere deadly because he would just escape it.

Comment: Because Thanos has the Space Stone and can just portal back

Comment: @Valorum Well he doesn't until the end of the battle in Endgame.

Comment: `If Thanos could simply jump out of it` ~> Well, he would have ended on universal trash dump where every lost is found.. The mighty Sakaar. And, he would have hard time getting out of it especially if he had landed in a time during Grandmaster's reign (time runs differently on Sakaar).

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 He may or may not have landed on Sakaar, we don't know if that was coincidence they both landed there or because that's just what happens when you fall out of it.